# Reasoning with Conjunctive Normal Forms

Tags: prolog, conjunctive-normal-form

I have this code, which I need to translate into the CNF (this is in preparation for the exam, so not a homework!):

```
p,q
r :- q
false :- p , s 
s :- t
t
```

Here's what I did:

```
p ^ q ^ (r V ~q) ^ (~p V ~s) ^ (s V ~t) ^ t

=  r
```

Is my reasoning correct?

There is another question here:

> You want to query the database with r. What clause, should you add to your database?

I don't understand this at all. After the simplification the database is basically r.
r is true, isn't it?

Comment: Multiple clauses in Prolog usually mean an "OR" relationship, so I would think you'd want, `(p ^ q) v (r v ~q) ...`. However, it's not clear that's what your list of expressions means since they aren't all properly formed Prolog clauses, and don't end in a period.

Comment: If you have time enough, I'd recommend you look at `library(clpb)` in SICStus, SWI, and others.

Comment: @j4nbur53 multiple *predicate clauses* mean "OR" not "AND". Perhaps you're referring to comma separated queries, which is "AND". For example, if I write `foo(X) :- bar(X). foo(X) :- bah(X).` that's two *predicate clauses* and it means `foo(X)` is true if `bar(X)` is true OR `bah(X)` is true. If I write, `foo(X) :- bar(X), bah(X).` then that means `foo(X)` is true if `bar(X)` is true AND `bah(X)` is true.

Comment: @j4nbur53 if I have a predicate clause, `foo(X) :- bar(X), bah(X).` then this consists of a rule head and body. It's a complete predicate clause. My understanding is that if I also have `foo(X) :- framus(X).` then that's another "clause" for the predicate `foo/1`.  In other words, the predicate `foo/1` consists of two *predicate clauses*. Perhaps that's a terminology misunderstanding on my part, but I'm not confused about conjunction versus disjunction. Can you point to a document that defines *predicate clause*? I would not want to continue with an incorrect understanding of the definition.

Comment: These two (predicate) clauses are joined by conjunction to form the theory of a **definite logic program (=without negation)**. They contain already disjunction since they read (~bar(X) \/ ~bah(X) \/ foo(X)) and (~framus(X) \/ foo(X)). You cannot join them with disjunction again, doesn't make any sense. See also what a Horn clause is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause (Disjunction form)

Answer (score 2):

The question "You want to query the database with r. What clause, should you add to your database?" refers to so called [refutation proofs](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/proof+by+contradiction). In a refutation proof one does not proof:

```
 Database |- Query
```

Instead one proofs:

```
 Database, ~Query |- f
```

In classical logic the two are the same. So in your example you would need to show that p ^ q ^ (r V ~q) ^ (~p V ~s) ^ (s V ~t) ^ t ^ ~r leads to a contradiction.

Bye

**Edit 14.02.2019:**
In case somebody is interested in Prolog code for converting propositonal formulas into CNF, see here https://gist.github.com/jburse/ca8d01e26c7cf176ea65eeb1bf916ea0#file-aspsat-p (Lines 43-87, requires Prolog Commons lists and ordset), you can convert a formula `F` into CNF `C`, by calling `norm(F,H), cnf(H,C)`.

The obtained CNF is already cleaned from trivial and subsumed clauses. If somebody is further interested in CNF test cases, see here http://gist.github.com/jburse/bf99239903847322321fabf6f49a5b84#file-casescls-p , it contains some hundred tautologies from Principia Mathematica, and some tenths fallacies collected otherwise.

Comment: It would also be possible to write a predicate that converts Prolog formulas into conjunctive normal form.

Comment: See Edit 14.02.2019